# How do I point my Squarespace domain to my Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, squarespace

I had a Squarespace website and domain, but I rebuilt it from scratch with heroku. Now I just need to transfer the domain I bought on Squarespace to my heroku app.

I guess in order to transfer your domain name away from Squarespace, you are supposed to go through some steps in the Admin dashboard, and at the end of it, they send you a code to use when you go to transfer it to a new hosting provider.

I followed these steps, and have the code, but I can't seem to find anywhere on the heroku site where I can enter it.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point your domain to your Heroku app you can follow these steps:

1. Go to your Heroku app settings and scroll down to "Add domain" and click that button
2. Enter your domain (www.example.com)
3. Heroku will create a DNS target for you (you will copy this into your squarespace DNS settings)
4. Login to your squarespace account and access your dns settings (under "Advanced Settings")
5. Add your Heroku DNS target there and save

   - e.g. www  CNAME heroku-dns-target

Comment: I did this, but a cname record alone won't work with squarespace, and squarespace doesn't support an alias record (which has worked for me in the past).  I used their domain forwarding service, and it works, but the URL for the page still shows the `.herokuapp.com.` which is less than ideal.  Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: I know this is  a long time ago but to have the domain name not change you have to use domain pointing and not forwarding.  Here is the link to how to do this on squarespace. https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/215744668-Pointing-a-Squarespace-domain.  Hopefully you got this working long ago.